# Data on file exchange partition is owned by 1000 and locked. How can I unlock this in OS X?

Tags: macos, permission, unix

I have created a file exchange permission that both OS X Lion and Ubuntu 12.04 can write to and read from. This partition is formatted as...

```
Apple_HFS Exchange
```

...with journaling disabled.
I have copied a folder from Ubuntu onto that partition. This folder appears as locked in OS X and I am not able to unlock this folder. The option is greyed out.

[image] [image]

The permission of this folder are:

```
drwxr-xr-x   4 1000      1000      136 11 Mai 14:43 Bilder
```

- How can I unlock this file in OS X?
- How can I prevent this from happening in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Unlocking the file

You can unlock files from within the terminal using the `chflags` command with `nouchg`:

```
sudo chflags -R nouchg Bilder
```

According to the man page for [chflags](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/chflags.1.html):

- `uchg` is the user immutable flag
- `no` in front of a flag removes the flag: `nouchg`

### Preventing this from happening in the future

A general solution would probably be to avoid handling permission altogether and using NTFS or FAT for an exchange partition.

However, I specifically voided such a solution (FAT32) this time, because I encountered serious errors the last time.